# string as global constant MISRA C++ Rule 3.7.2

Tags: c++, c++20, misra

I have declared some std::string global constants in my header file.

Const.hpp:

```cpp
struct Constants {
    const static std::string CONFIG_PATH;
    const static std::string VERBOSE;
    const static std::string LOG_PATH;
    const static std::string HELP;
    const static std::string PORT;
};
```

In my code file these constants are initialized.

Const.cpp:

```cpp
const std::string Constants::CONFIG_PATH { "config-path" };
const std::string Constants::VERBOSE { "verbose" };
const std::string Constants::LOG_PATH { "log-path" };
const std::string Constants::HELP { "help" };
const std::string Constants::PORT { "port" };
```

I use sonarcloud to help me to minimalize issues in the code, but there is a problem with these constants. It says this:

```
This global constant is not statically initialized, make it "constexpr" or remove it by passing the value as a function argument.
```

I cannot make them `constexpr` since it is string and not char array.

What to do to resolve this?

Comment: why not use constexpr std::string_view? Or can't you use C++17.Or use `inline const char*` in your header file. It is not strictly necessary to have std::string globals.

Comment: Is there a reason to allocate it dynamically, instead of using static allocation? It is const anyway.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code. I compiled and ran in VS22 with compiler set for both C++14 and then C++20. Worked both times. When I have problems with global constants, I sometimes just wrap them in a function. It is not your issue, but see [Static Initialization Order Fiasco](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/siof), just in case it is news to you.

Comment: There are both a C++20 and MISRA tag, but I was under the impression that MISRA C++:202x wasn't yet released. Could you please confirm that you can target the C++20 version of the Standard?

Comment: `const static std::string` in a header doesn't really make any sense – you're giving them internal linkage, but then only defining them in one translation unit? None of that is reasonable, I feel that you have an error in reducing your actual code for the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wants you to prevent the static variable order initialization fiasco. I have read about their diagnostics, they seem to want you to write such code (I skip similarities):

```
struct Constants {
    static const std::string& CONFIG_PATH();
};
```

```
const std::string& Constants::CONFIG_PATH() {
  static const std::string config_path { "config-path" };
  return config_path;
}
```

And usage `Constants::CONFIG_PATH` --> `Constants::CONFIG_PATH()`.

Or maybe it just wants

```
struct Constants {
    inline static const std::string CONFIG_PATH { "config-path" };
};
```

Comment: When I used `inline static const std::string CONFIG_PATH { "config-path" };` it did not change anything, so I used the method approach and it works, thanks